# How to print number with predefined exponent base (pgf)?

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfmath

How can I print a number with some predefined base of power  of 10 (exponent base) using `\pgfmathprintnumber`

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}
    \pgfset{fpu=true}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\en}{1/sqrt(2e-3*2e-6)/(2*pi)}
    \pgfset{fpu=false}
    \pgfmathprintnumber[]{\en} % need 25 * 10^2
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `pgf`, even with the `fpu` library, is poor in computations: the number, with `bc` turns out to be 2516.46060522435201602583; with `xfp` I get 2516.460605224352, which is much more accurate than 2516.3

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Сan you, please, put the answer here with solution with `xpf`?

Comment: Skillmon already did it.

Comment: @egreg The PGF fpu is just completely false advertising, because it doesn't actually implement an FPU.  Instead it just rescales all operands to avoid `Dimension too large`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does something like that. It allows you to set a fixed exponent. I did not dare to touch the `\pgfmathprintnumber` macro, so I wrote a macro `\pgfmathprintnumberFE`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,custom exponent/.initial=2}%
\newcommand{\pgfmathprintnumberFE}[2][]{%
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,#1}%
\pgfset{fpu=true}%
\pgfmathparse{#2}%
\pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfmathresult}{\F}{\M}{\E}%
\pgfset{fpu=false}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\redexp}{\E-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/number format/custom exponent}}%
\ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/number format/custom exponent}=0
\ensuremath{\pgfmathprintnumber{\M}}%
\else
\pgfmathsetmacro{\newnum}{\M*pow(10,\redexp)}%
\ensuremath{\pgfmathprintnumber{\newnum}\cdot10^{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/number format/custom exponent}}}%
\fi
\endgroup}
\begin{document}
    \pgfmathprintnumberFE[custom exponent=2]{1/sqrt(2e-3*2e-6)/(2*pi)}

    \pgfmathprintnumberFE[custom exponent=1]{1/sqrt(2e-3*2e-6)/(2*pi)}

    \pgfmathprintnumberFE[custom exponent=4]{123456}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Thank you. Interesting, why this possibility not implemented in in regular funds of `\pgfmathprintnumber`?

Comment: @sergiokapone I cannot exclude that it some is included in some way, but I did not see an obvious way. The only thing I know that comes close is `@sci exponent mark` (see p. 1043 of pgfmanual v3.1.4) but it has a warning attached that it is not to be used to change the exponent.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `siunitx`. We have to convert the `fpu` number to scientific notation (the output of pgf's fpu is a bit strange for other packages).

```latex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\fixedexponent[2]
  {%
    \num
      [%
        fixed-exponent=#1,
        scientific-notation=fixed,
        round-mode=places,
        round-precision=0,
      ]{#2}%
  }

\begin{document}
    \pgfset{fpu=true}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\en}{1/sqrt(2e-3*2e-6)/(2*pi)}
    \pgfset{fpu=false}
    \pgfmathprintnumber[]{\en} % need 25 * 10^2
    % convert the number to scientific notation
    \pgfset{fpu=true,fpu/output format=sci}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\en{\en}
    \pgfset{fpu=false}
    \fixedexponent{2}{\en}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could change the product symbol before the exponent with `exponent-product=\cdot` in the options of `\num` (or `siunitx`).

**EDIT:** As suggested by egreg one could use `xfp`, which uses the floating point engine of LaTeX3, for the calculations.

```latex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand\fixedexponent[2]
  {%
    \num
      [%
        fixed-exponent=#1,
        scientific-notation=fixed,
        round-mode=places,
        round-precision=0,
      ]{\fpeval{#2}}%
  }

\begin{document}
    \fixedexponent{2}{1/sqrt(2e-3*2e-6)/(2*pi)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you remove all PGF code and do `\usepackage{xfp}` instead, just `\fixedexponent{2}{\fpeval{1/sqrt(2e-3*2e-6)/(2*pi)}}` will do what's wanted (and the computation is actually much more accurate; test with more decimal digits to see.

Comment: @egreg good point, added it as an alternative, though I directly built `\fpeval` into `\fixedexponent`.